# Python cannot ssh to a server and print the expected output using subprocess

Tags: python, ssh

I read the IP address of a machine from a text file and want to ssh to that server and run a few shell commands to get the desired output.

In the text `IP_address.txt`, I have provided the IP address which is `182.x.x.x`

Here is my code snippet:

```
fo = open("ip_address.txt", "r")
    data = fo.readlines()
    for line in data:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % line],shell = True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout= subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        ssh.stdin.write(">en\n")
        ssh.stdin.write("_shell\n")
        ssh.stdin.write("ls -ltr\n")
        result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
        if result == []:
            error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
            print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
        else:
            print result
```

When I print result, it is `[]`, meaning empty. The server where I am trying to run the script has passwordless connection to the server I am trying to SSH to.

I am simply trying to execute similar commands when I do manual steps from this server which are:-

```
ssh 182.x.x.x
en
_shell
ls -ltr
```

But this throws me an error instead:-

```
    ERROR: ['usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]\n', '           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]\n', '           [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]\n', '           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]\n', '           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]\n', '           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]\n', '           [user@]hostname [command]\n']
```

I am not able to resolve this error as I am not able to figure out what is wrong with this code. Any help?
P.S - I want make the ssh connection using subprocess only and not paramiko or any other class libraries.
Thanks

Comment: What are 'en' and '_shell' are supposed to do ?

Comment: en creates the shell environment and _shell takes it to the shell command line. Basically these are just commands I want to execute once I ssh to that server. But first I am not sure that it is even making the ssh connection to that machine.

Comment: have you ssh'd to that machine before? is ssh waiting for input? like adding a key, password, user etc? this will stop it in it's tracks and you will send your commands into stdin before making a connection. Also log in to the machine and check last to see if connection has been made at all.

Answer (score 0):

try to call your ssh like that:

```
sh = subprocess.Popen("ssh %s" % line,shell = True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout= subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

when calling with shell=True all arguments in a list are passed to the shell rather to the app from first argument, so in this case you just want to pass your ssh some.ip.add.ress to the shell rather than passing ssh (this gets executed straight away) and then passing ip string after